# Slow mysql delete query using IN statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a delete query which should run pretty much instantly

```
DELETE FROM
  TableA
WHERE
  TableA.SomeID IN (SELECT DISTINCT TableB.SomeID FROM TableB WHERE TableB.Something = Blah)
```

If I execute the query inside the IN statement on its own then it runs instantly. If I then comma separate the results of that and paste them into the outer query then that query runs instantly. However, when I run them together it takes 24 seconds. It's like the inner query is getting executed once per row. I also tried modifying it to use an EXISTS statement but that was also slow. Do I need to resort to a temp table for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested subquery will be slow.  Try using a JOIN instead:

```
DELETE A
FROM TableA AS A
INNER JOIN TableB AS B
    ON A.SomeID = B.SomeID 
WHERE B.Something = Blah
```

Also, ensure that `TableA.SomeID` and `TableB.SomeID` both have an index on them, to maximize the performance of the join.

Comment: Ok, I did previously try that but it was giving me an error about safe deletes. I've ended up turning that warning off and the join executes instantly. I'd still like to know why my original query is so slow when both queries on their own run instantly and is there a way to make the original query fast while retaining the in clause? The reason I would like to know is that this sort of thing crops up all the time where 2 queries run fast but combined together they are slow.

Comment: It's executing slowly because you're structuring it as a nested subquery.  As such, MySQL executes the subquery for each row matching the outer query (every row in TableA).

Comment: That is interesting as it's different to my experience with Microsoft's SQL Server. Is there some way to stop that happening besides putting the results in a temp table? (assuming we still wanted to use the IN statement for any reason)

Comment: Yeah, MS-SQL handles nested subqueries differently.  MySQL interestingly does better with correlated subqueries, which goes against logic if you come from MS-SQL.  The best way to structure subqueries, in my experience with MySQL is to use derived tables (select from (subquery) as alias), but you don't need that here, and it wouldn't help you much with your delete warnings.  A temp table would likely be the best solution for what I think you want to do, but isn't necessarily feasible, depending on how you're running this (e.g. from php).  You could always make a stored procedure out of it! :)

Answer (score 2):

Doing it as an inner join should be a lot faster than doing an IN + DISTINCT

```
DELETE A
FROM 
    TableA A
    INNER JOIN TableB B ON B.SomeID = A.SomeID AND B.Something = Blah
```